# Skinning the LoopingSelector from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am trying to reuse the LoopingSelector for my own collection. Technically everything is working just fine nut I am trying to skin the items presented in the list and having less success there.

Adding a DataTemplate with my own data is no problem. The problem is that I want the single element shown when the LoopingSelector is collapsed shown with a different style then when it is expanded. I can set the style on the LoopingSelector bus as far as I can tell I need to set the style on the LoopingSelectorItem and can´t find any way to do so.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not achieve this with the "Normal", "Expanded" and "Selected" states?

What have you tried?

Comment: The LoopingSelector or its ItemTemplate have no states, those are defined on the LoopingSelectorItem and I can find no way to edit that template or style. I tried copying the LoopingSelectorItem style from the Generic.xaml to my App.xaml but any changes in there are not picked up, I am guessing because SL3 has no default Styles and I can get to the LoopingSelectorItem to specify the style to use.

Comment: @Maurice LoopingSelectorItem has these states.

Comment: @Matt. Yes I know, just can't figure out how to set them as the LoopingSelectorItem is created inside of the LoopingSelector and its Template or Style doesn't seem to be exposed. That is unless I am missing something obvious here. I know what they are by checking the Generic.xaml, now I still need to figure the changing part.

Comment: Have you looked at `DatePickerPage.xaml` in the toolkit source. It appears to do what you're trying to.

Comment: It changes the DataTemplate which works just fine except you can't change the VSM states in there. If I edit the <Style TargetType="primitives:LoopingSelectorItem"> in the Generic.xaml my VSM changes work just fine but I can't figure out how to do that in my own app. That is short of a custom build of the toolkit which is always an option.

Comment: Sorry, thought it did style changes there too. I've built several customized versions of the toolkit for projects. It's not something to fear if you need something for a specific solution.

Comment: There is a DataTemplate that styles the contents of each item and a VSM that makes the page flip when you close it. I can't change the VSM for the items there. But than I am no XAML expert so I was expecting it to something I just didn't know. A custom build might just be the way I go on this. Thanks.